# Overload operator== on std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++11

I was considering overloading the equality and ordering operators of std::shared_ptr for a particular type. So if I have the following

```
struct Foo { /* Stuff */ };

bool operator==( const std::shared_ptr<Foo>& lhs, const std::shared_ptr<Foo>& rhs )
{
    // Do something reasonable for equality using the Foo instances
}
```

So this would mean equality would no longer be just pointer equality. Is there a downside or some ugly pitfall to doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It's completely illegal and banned by Standard. Horrible nasal demons ensue.

Comment: It seems very likely that this is indeed invalid, but either a quote from the standard or a real implementation where it breaks would probably be more convincing.

Comment: I agree with hvd I was hoping for something a little more enlightening. It would appear to be valid C++ so in what way is it illegal?