# std::min element weird behavior when class is wrapped by shared_ptr

Tags: c++, stl, operator-overloading

I've had a long debugging session (6 hours or more). I was debugging my A* algorithm implementation.

After checking every possibility, after adding logging, debugging step by step etc. I finally found the answer. Basically, it all boils down to one line, where I search for the minimum value in a vector.

Check this out:

```
auto open_set = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<node>>{start_node};

std::shared_ptr<node> current;
while (!open_set.empty())
{
    current = *std::min_element(open_set.begin(), open_set.end());
```

The `current = *std::min_element(open_set.begin(), open_set.end());` line was supposed to find the lowest `node` in a vector. This is my `node` implementation:

```
class node
{
public:
    node() : G(0), H(0) {}
    node(const QPoint& p) : pos(p), G(0), H(0) {}
    bool operator==(const node& o) const { return pos == o.pos;}
    bool operator==(const QPoint& o) const { return pos == o; }
    bool operator!=(const node& o) const { return pos != o.pos; }
    bool operator<(const node& o) const { return  G + H < o.G + o.H; }
    QPoint pos;
    std::shared_ptr<node> parent;
    int G;
    int H;
};
```

So I have the `operator<` needed for searching for `min_element`. The problem is, after many times looking at my logs I saw that I had a `node` with i.e. G = 8, H = 10, and node G = 10, H = 10. Guess which was picked as the `min_element` -> the second! I had no idea why and I was furious, so I wrote a simple lambda to compare nodes:

```
current = *std::min_element(open_set.begin(), open_set.end(),
                            [&] (const std::shared_ptr<node>& lhs, const std::shared_ptr<node>& rhs)
                            {
                                return lhs->G + lhs->H < rhs->G + rhs->H;
                            });
```

And boom, this:

[image]

changed to this:

[image]

Clearly, you can see that the first one is wrong. And I checked it many times, it always works well now, so the problem was really here.

So my question here is why didn't it work when I was using `std::min_element`. Does it have to do something with the fact I have the `std::vector` of `std::shared_ptr<node>`s and not of just `node`s? Do I have to write `operator<` in `node` class differently?

Comment: [`Note that the comparison operators for shared_ptr simply compare pointer values; the actual objects pointed to are not compared.`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_cmp)

Comment: So writing `operator<` for `node` is pointless here, right? I have to use lambda or define i.e. `my_smart_pointer: shared_ptr` and overload the `operator<` there?

Comment: `I have to use lambda` Or a vector of nodes. `or define i.e. my_smart_pointer: shared_ptr` Not exactly sure how this is meant. Writing a comparator for `std::shared_ptr<Node>` should work.

Comment: But I then I would write it outside `shared_ptr` class - would the compiler find it?

Comment: Comparison functions can be [free functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison)

Comment: Yes, but `shared_ptr` already has a `operator<`. Even the compiler tells me that: `algorithm_utils.h:33: error: C2084: function 'bool operator <(const std::shared_ptr<node> &,const std::shared_ptr<node> &)' already has a body`

Comment: And also, this: `https://stackoverflow.com/a/32939090/10638608` (I guess it applies to `operator<` as well)

Comment: Alright, then you need to pass a function/a lambda I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ documentation is very clear on why this issue is occuring:

If you look at the page on shared_ptr:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_cmp

> Note that the comparison operators for shared_ptr simply compare
>   pointer values; the actual objects pointed to are not compared. Having
>   operator< defined for shared_ptr allows shared_ptrs to be used as keys
>   in associative containers, like std::map and std::set.

But there is way to get std::min to achieve the behavior you want. You can implement a comparison function object or use a lambda like you already have.

```
class node
{
public:
    node() : G(0), H(0) {}
    node(int x, int y) : G(x), H(y) {}

    bool operator<(const node& o) const { return  (G + H) < (o.G + o.H); }

    int G;
    int H;
};

struct NodeComparer
{
    bool operator()(std::shared_ptr<node> const& lhs, std::shared_ptr<node>  const& rhs) const
    {
        return *lhs < *rhs;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<node> a = std::make_shared<node>(3, 6);
    std::shared_ptr<node> b = std::make_shared<node>(1, 1);
    std::shared_ptr<node> c = std::make_shared<node>(2, 2);

    auto open_set = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<node>>
    { 
        a,b,c
    };

    std::shared_ptr<node> current;

    current = *std::min_element(open_set.begin(), open_set.end(), NodeComparer());


    getchar();

}
```

As soon as you wrap node up in shared_ptr you are no longer dealing with the node type, you are dealing with the shared_ptr type. And so you should anticipate that all of the operations you do on the data will reflect that. For example, the sizeof() operator applied to a shared_ptr node will give you back the size of a shared_ptr not the size of a node. 
In the same way, when you do a comparison on two shared_ptr's it is the shared_ptr comparison operator that is defined for that type.

Comment: Thanks for even better clarification! That's what I did, I actually used lambda, but the solution with a comparer class is an elegant way as well!